# How to Force an Apex Sharing Recalculation DML Exception?

Tags: apex, dmlexception, apex-managed-sharing

I have implemented the following Sharing Recalculation class from the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_recalc.htm)

```
        try {
           // Delete the existing sharing records.
           // This allows new sharing records to be written from scratch.
            Delete oldJobShrs;
            
           // Insert the new sharing records and capture the save result. 
           // The false parameter allows for partial processing if multiple records are 
           // passed into operation. 
           Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(newJobShrs,false);
           
           // Process the save results for insert.
           for(Database.SaveResult sr : lsr){
               if(!sr.isSuccess()){
                   // Get the first save result error.
                   Database.Error err = sr.getErrors()[0];
                   
                   // Check if the error is related to trivial access level.
                   // Access levels equal or more permissive than the object's default 
                   // access level are not allowed. 
                   // These sharing records are not required and thus an insert exception 
                   // is acceptable. 
                   if(!(err.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION  
                                     &&  err.getMessage().contains('AccessLevel'))){
                       // Error is not related to trivial access level.
                       // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter.
                     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                     String[] toAddresses = new String[] {emailAddress}; 
                     mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
                     mail.setSubject('Apex Sharing Recalculation Exception');
                     mail.setPlainTextBody(
                       'The Apex sharing recalculation threw the following exception: ' + 
                             err.getMessage());
                     Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                   }
               }
           }   
        } catch(DmlException e) {
           // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter on failure.
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {emailAddress}; 
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
            mail.setSubject('Apex Sharing Recalculation Exception');
            mail.setPlainTextBody(
              'The Apex sharing recalculation threw the following exception: ' + 
                        e.getMessage());
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
```

I successfully covered the try clause (As I happen to be working on a similar Job custom object), but I don't understand how can I cause a DML Exception in this case to cover the catch clause).

The documentation test class does not provide a way to cover that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's literally impossible for your code to throw an exception that can be caught, which is why you're having a hard time covering it. Remove the try-catch block entirely. Keep in mind that if you exceed governor limits, you'll not be able to recover anyways. However, also note that you're sending emails in a loop. This will throw an uncatchable exception if more than 10 errors occur (you can only call `Messaging.sendEmail` 10 times per transaction). Accumulate all emails into a list, and send the email after looping through all the results.

Comment: N.B. I'm going to go write a doc bug report on this. Salesforce documentation should never enshrine bad habits like sending emails inside a loop.